# Make KeyEvent as variable

Tags: java, keylistener

I have:

```
KeyEvent keyLeft;
KeyEvent keyRight;
```

as variables.

and in my Class constructor I want something like:

```
keyLeft = new KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;   // or it could be VK_A 
keyRight = new KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT; // and VK_S
```

This piece code doesn't work it's only for understanding.

i don't know if you understand what I'm trying to accoplish. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, I don't understand. KeyEvent.VK_LEFT is a constant of type `int`. It's not a constructor. What are you retying to achieve, at a higher level? Explain as if I was a 9-year old boy.

Comment: My point is: I have keyPressed and keyReleased functions, one of them looks like this: 
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
    "do something"
}

and i want:

if (e.getKeyCode() == keyRight) where keyRight is a variable where i can put any key.

Comment: And? What's the problem with that? If you want a variable that is equal to VK_RIGHT but is named keyRight, then what you need is `int keyRight = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;`. That's useless, though.

Comment: Yes, i found out that it's integer. Thank You :)

Comment: I am assuming he will use these other variables so he can re-map user controls from a settings file or through the app itself